# Heirarchical nested generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a chain of hierarchically nested generic interfaces, which for examples sake look like this:

```
ICar<TWheels, TBolts>
where TWheels : IWheels<TBolts>
where TBolts : IBolts
{
    IEnumerable<TWheels> Wheels { get; set; }
}

IWheels<TBolts>
where TBolts : IBolts
{
    IEnumerable<TBolts> Wheels { get; set; }
}

IBolts
{

}
```

Is this a sensible way of handling these generic interfaces?

It makes defining methods look like this:

```
public TCar GetCar<TWheels, TBolts>(int id)
where TCar : ICar<TWheels, TBolts>
where TWheels : IWheels<TBolts>
where TBolts : IBolts
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to reduce this code signature?

Comment: Probably you can define the parameters on the classes instead of methods. (Unless those are static of course.)

Comment: Since you're returning `TCar`, I don't think you need that first `where` clause, since you're essentially just imposing it on yourself.  Just declare it as returning `ICar<TWheels, TBolts>` in the first place

Comment: [Deleted as answer and posted as comment]- This seems to be complecating the problem with too many interfaces. Try to use antipatterns.

Comment: @Amit do you have an example?

Comment: This is problem of Interface bloat https://github.com/Skookum/design-patterns/blob/master/anti-patterns/interface-bloat/README.md

Comment: @Amit This sounds like it's exactly not that, where things have already been split out into separate interfaces.  Interface bloat, as defined by that link, is too many things on one interface covering too much, not too many interfaces where each one deals with a specific area.

Comment: Ok. Agreed. Partially. But does it give surety that in given example all of the objects implementing those interfaces can perform the given operations? If not then what we will call it?

Answer (score 2):

Generics in C# should be used very carefully to avoid problems like you've faced.
I'd recommend to revise interfaces hierarchy and throw generics away:

```
interface ICar
{
    IEnumerable<IWheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

interface IWheel
{
    IEnumerable<IBolt> Bolts { get; set; }
}

interface IBolt
{
}
```

Then it would be great to look at use-cases, where those interfaces participate.
May be, there will be very rare cases, when you'll need `IR16Wheel` instead of `IWheel`, and type casting will be enough.
May be, it will be enough to pair non-generic interfaces with generic ones:

```
interface IWheel<TBolt> : IWheel
    where TBolt : IBolt
{
    IEnumerable<TBolt> Bolts { get; set; }
}
```

and use non-generics with methods like this:

```
public ICar GetCar(int id) { }
```

but also use generics in more specific cases.

Comment: Sorry. Your answer is good pointer but not the solution needed for "Is there any way to reduce this code signature?" So, downvoted.

Comment: @Amit: re-design types is the only solution here. You're completely wrong.

Comment: @Amit Often the "right" answer to a question is to make the questioner think about it in a different way.  See the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  In this case it has answered "how to reduce this code signature", the answer being by redesigning the inheritance chain.

Comment: @Dennis - I agree on re-design and I have not claim any answer to prove wrong.

Comment: @James - Agree. But XY problem also tells that different way should not lead to different goal itself.